# how to remove a view from stackview and distribute the other fillequally

Tags: swift, io, uistackview

i have a stackview desing in storyboard with 5 view inside composed of 1 buttom, a small view with a label and a button. like this.
[image]

what i want is to remove one of the the view let say the one with orange background.
i tried this on viewdidload

```
stackview.view2.isHiden = true
stackview.view2.removeFromSuperview()
```

this remove the view and all elements but the remaing does not distribute as expected any idea how to achive this

Comment: What is the expected result? I'm guessing that you want the other items to take all the available space and be equal to each other. Have you tried setting the Distribution attribute of the stack view to "Fill Equally"?

Comment: that's the expected behavir but the result is nt what i  expected in deed one view get wider and the ther stay at the same size but not fillequality

Comment: Did you try to do something like `stackView.setNeedsLayout()` and/or `stackView.layoutIfNeeded`? BTW you don't need to hide if you removeFromSuperView anyway. 

Anyway, could you share a screenshot of the wrong layout after you remove the view. Maybe you have not set up proper constraints and settings for the stack view in you storyboard.

Answer (score -1):

```
// Appears to remove the first arranged view from the stack.
// The view is still inside the stack, it's just no longer visible, and no longer contributes to the layout.

let firstView = stackView.arrangedSubviews[0]
firstView.isHidden = true
```